# jQueryMobile 'Filter Select' not working on mobile devices

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile

We currently implemented the 'Select Filter' function provided by jQueryMobile on our webApp. This is working fine on desktop browsers, but this isn't working on mobile devices.

Example:

```
<form>
    <input data-type="search" id="searchForSelect">
</form>
<select id="anotherSelect" data-filter="true" data-input="#searchForSelect">
    <option value="A">Option A</option>
    <option value="B">Option B</option>
    <option value="C">Option C</option>
</select>
```

It simply doesn't filter my content. No errors, no crashes, just no filter.

If you browse to the following URL on a mobile device: [Link](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-rc.1/dist/demos/filterable/). You will see that the filter on the select element isn't working (so it's not a failure in my own code).

Has anyone else experienced this bug? Is there a work-around?

Thanks.

Comment: working fine under iOS. which mobile device are you using? old android operating systems maybe don't support full jquerymobile functionality.

Comment: I'm using the iOS Simulator(iPad) on a iMac. I also use a Galaxy tab 2 10.1 . Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: which android version do you have on the galaxy tab? and which browser do you use?

Comment: The filter adds `.ui-screen-hidden { display: none !important }` to options, it seems that Safari doesn't support `display: none` on `option`.

Comment: here is a work around, where you `disable` options instead of hiding them, which works on all browsers except for IE7 and before http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Kezn4/

Comment: @tronc I'm currently using Android 4.1.2 on the Galaxy tab, and I'm experiencing the issue on both the Stock browser and Chrome browser.

Comment: @Omar Thanks for your input, I'm going to give that a try, I will keep this thread up to date. Edit: I'm afraid your fiddle isn't working properly on mobile devices (somehow). Instead of hiding the other select elements, they're greyed out. On my desktop browser (Chrome & FF) it is removing the elements. Can't find a flaw in your code..

Comment: My code disables options instead of hiding them. I test the code on iPhone 5 safari. It's not a final solution, just a hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to duplicate your problem on an older iPad running iOS 5.1.1.  It seems like the problem may be related to that particular version of jQuery Mobile.  When I tried the example located at [this URL](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/) I did not have any issues.